# Meteor Routing Error : There is no route for the path: /

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, flow-router

I have updated Meteor to Meteor 1.3.2.4. and facing the issue. I have also updated all the packages in their latest version.

**Error : There is no route for the path: /**

I tried the both in both environment "**meteor**" and  "**meteor run --production**" the same error will displayed in console.

I have installed the following packages.

```
accounts-oauth                   1.1.12  Common code for OAuth-based login services
accounts-password                1.1.8  Password support for accounts
autopublish                      1.0.7  (For prototyping only) Publish the entire database to all clients
blaze-html-templates             1.0.4  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
cfs:gridfs                       0.0.33  GridFS storage adapter for CollectionFS
cfs:standard-packages            0.5.9  Filesystem for Meteor, collectionFS
ecmascript                       0.4.3  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
email                            1.0.12  Send email messages
es5-shim                         4.5.10  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
flowkey:bootstrap-tour           1.1.0  A Meteor.js / Blaze integration for bootstrap-tour
insecure                         1.0.7  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client
jquery                           1.11.8  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
kadira:blaze-layout              2.3.0  Layout Manager for Blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
kadira:flow-router               2.12.1  Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
meteor-base                      1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience                1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                            1.1.7  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
pauli:accounts-linkedin          1.3.1  Accounts service for LinkedIn accounts
service-configuration            1.0.9  Manage the configuration for third-party services
session                          1.1.5  Session variable
standard-minifier-css            1.0.6  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js             1.0.6  Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
themeteorchef:jquery-validation  1.14.0  jQuery Validation by jzaefferer, repackaged for Meteor.
tomi:upload-jquery               2.4.0  Client template for uploads using "jquery-file-upload" from blueimp
tomi:upload-server               1.3.4  Upload server for Meteor. Allows to save and serve files from arbitrary directory
tracker                          1.0.13  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
u2622:persistent-session         0.4.4  Persistently store Session data on the client
zimme:active-route               2.3.2  Active route helpers
```

My routing.js is 
exposed = FlowRouter.group();

```
exposed.route('/', {
    triggersEnter: function () {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn() && typeof Meteor.userId() !== 'undefined') {
            FlowRouter.go("/dashboard");
        }
    },
    action: function () {
        BlazeLayout.render("mainTemplate", {content: "homePage"});
    }
});

exposed.route('/login', {
    triggersEnter: function () {
        if (Meteor.userId() !== null) {
            FlowRouter.go("/dashboard");
        }
    },
    action: function (params) {
        BlazeLayout.render("mainTemplate", {content: "login"});
    }
});
```

Comment: did you `import` your `routing.js` file in your client's `main.js` file?

Comment: How to import in main.js i didn't know.

Comment: if you are not familiar with import/export module, i'd highly recommend you to use meteor version 1.2. you'll be able to do things much quickly. Or you can learn ecmascript2015+ first.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I have also tried with 1.2.1 on my another system. But facing the issue "There is no route for the path: /" when using "meteor --production"

Comment: This Issue Solved: I just moved my routing.js into "lib/routing.js" now its working as expected for me.

Comment: In my case I removed dopzone package and installed using  meteor npm install --save dropzone after that this problem is resolved. Try removing package one by one and check which package is causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and fixed it by getting rid of console errors that were present in the development build.

Think the reason my development build was working, but production build wasn't, is because of JS files being concatenated for production, meaning that this error was preventing subsequent code from running.

**So, motto is, make sure there are no errors being thrown, as they will lead to more issues when concatenating file for production!**

(The package in question was autoform-hint, but don't think that is particularly relevant.)