# Meteor app can't find routes

Tags: meteor

New to meteor. Just cloned a git repo, and upon launching the app, I get a `router.js:347 There is no route for the path: /` error.

This is my route for root in imports/startup/client/routes.js

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: 'Home',
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('app_body', {tabs: 'tabs', inbox: 'inbox', upload: 'upload', invite: 'invite'});
        console.log('root loaded');
    },
});
```

Here is the list of packages

```
    accounts-facebook                         1.0.10  Login service for Facebook accounts
accounts-password                         1.2.14* Password support for accounts
alanning:roles                            1.2.15  Authorization package for Meteor
aldeed:collection2                        2.9.1  Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
aldeed:simple-schema                      1.5.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and autoform.
arillo:flow-router-helpers                0.5.2  Template helpers for flow-router
blaze-html-templates                      1.0.4  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
check                                     1.2.3  Check whether a value matches a pattern
dburles:collection-helpers                1.0.4  Transform your collections with helpers that you define
ecmascript                                0.5.7* Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
email                                     1.1.16* Send email messages
es5-shim                                  4.6.13* Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
hpx7:youtube-iframe-player                0.4.15  Control YouTube's embedded player using Meteor
http                                      1.2.8* Make HTTP calls to remote servers
jazeee:spiderable-longer-timeout          1.2.13  Extended spiderable package: SSL, caching, longer timeout, no stdin issues, publish flag
jchristman:tagsinput-autocomplete-edited  1.1.0+ A combination of the mizzao:autocomplete library and a tagsinput-like functionality
jquery                                    1.11.9  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
kadira:blaze-layout                       2.3.0  Layout Manager for Blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
kadira:flow-router                        2.12.1  Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
keepnox:perfect-scrollbar                 0.6.8  Perfect-scrollbar packaged for meteor
manuel:reactivearray                      1.0.5  Reactive Array for Meteor
matb33:collection-hooks                   0.8.3* Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for insert/update/remove/find/findOne
meteor-base                               1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteorhacks:aggregate                     1.3.0  Proper MongoDB aggregations support for Meteor
mobile-experience                         1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile user experience
momentjs:moment                           2.14.4  Moment.js (official): parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates - official Meteor packaging
mongo                                     1.1.10* Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
reactive-dict                             1.1.8  Reactive dictionary
reactive-var                              1.0.10  Reactive variable
sacha:spin                                2.3.1  Simple spinner package for Meteor
saucecode:timezoned-synced-cron           1.2.11  Fork of original w/ timezone support. Define and run scheduled jobs across multiple servers.
session                                   1.1.6  Session variable
spiderable                                1.0.13  Makes the application crawlable to web spiders
standard-minifier-css                     1.1.8* Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js                      1.1.8* Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tomwasd:flow-router-seo                   0.0.3  A simple way to set the title and meta tags for sites using flow router
tracker                                   1.1.0  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap                            3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
```

What is it that is causing the app not to find the routes file? I have looked through the following posts for some guidance, but have found none.

[Meteor Routing Error : There is no route for the path: /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831628/meteor-routing-error-there-is-no-route-for-the-path)

https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/issues/608

https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/issues/185

http://coderchronicles.org/2016/04/08/getting-started-with-meteor-1-3-react-and-flowrouter/

Any help solving the problem would be appreciated.  I feel like I'm missing something simple.

-S

**project file structure

```
imports/
  startup/
    client/
      index.js               
      routes.js                 
    server/
      fixtures.js             
      index.js               
  api/               
     server/
        publications.js       

  ui/
    components/               

    layouts/                   
    pages/                     
client/
  main.js 
  head.js
  main.js                   
server/
  main.js
  fixtures.js
 server-global.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the routes file into your app's main container?

For example, if you have a `/client/main.js` file that gets loaded from client side at startup, then it should include the import reference to routes file as follows:

`import '/imports/startup/client';`

Or, `import '/imports/startup/client/routes.js';`

Comment: Yes, I have `import './routes.js';
import './helpers.js';
import './client-global.js';`  In my index.js in /startup/client (same folder as my routes)

Answer (score 0):

Put your route file in 'imports/starup/lib' (lib - for example). In fast-render package recommended use 'lib', if you wanna use it. If no - 'client';

Then make sure you imported your route file in 'root/client/main.js';

Please, read this part of docs: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure

It is very helpful article.

**UPD:** 
Please, remove duplicate files in your client/main.js 
When, in client/main.js

```
import '/imports/startup/client';
```

In your imports/startup/client/index.js

```
import './routes.js';
```

And now it will work. 
Dont forget, you must import all views you wanna use in your route.

Comment: I moved my routes to imports/startup/client/lib and changed my routes import to `import '../lib/routes.js';` but I am still getting the same error

Comment: not 'import' - 'imports'. 

In your root directory u have at least two folders and files - 
client/main.js and server/main.js
In your  client/main.js - use import '/imports/startup/lib/router.js';

Comment: Hey, I tried that, unfortunately, the app still cant find the routes...

Comment: Can u share your project file structure?

Comment: i added structure to top

Comment: I tried that. Still have same error startup/client/index has `import '../lib/routes.js';` and client/main.js has `import '../imports/startup/client';
import '../imports/startup/lib/routes.js'` I dont see duplication of files.  The duplication of main.js was just a typo when I wrote the tree

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.  Instead of launching with `meteor run`, need to launch with `meteor --settings settings.json --production`